# How to perform a round robin assignment of records to only logged in users

Tags: apex, trigger

I have installed a round robin record assignment (Un managed package) application from app exchange and now I woud like to modify the code to have this work only for logged in users in salesforce.

I have tried retrieving the session info from "Authsession" object but I could see a multiple sessions opened for a user But I am not sure whether a user is currently logged in or logged out and also I could see the sessions disappear for a particular user if and only if he logs out only through the logout option other wise if he simply closes a tab then that user sessions still exist under sessions management (our ORG has a session time out set to 12 hours).

Also, how can we know that a user is logged out from salesforce ?

Any thoughts would be really appreciated...!!!!
Thanks in advance ..!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding you cannot modify the code (`Apex, visualforce`) of package installed from `Appexchange`

if you access an `Apex Class` that is installed from `Appexchange`
 you can see this :

[image]

and for the logged out users, you can find the answer in those links :

[Stackexchange answer 1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65562/using-soql-how-can-i-tell-which-users-are-currently-logged-into-salesforce)

[stack exchange answer 2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65562/using-soql-how-can-i-tell-which-users-are-currently-logged-into-salesforce)

[AuthSession object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_authsession.htm)

Comment: Actually its a unmanaged package and we can modify the components.